# C++ Operator precedence for Bitwise AND and Logical OR

Tags: c++, bitwise-operators, logical-operators, operator-precedence

From [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence), I got to know that operator precedence of Bitwise AND is higher than Logical OR.
However, the following program gives an unexpected output.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int a = 1;
int b = 2;
int c = 4;

if ( a++ || b++ & c++)
{
    cout <<a <<" " << b <<" " << c <<" " <<endl;
}
return 0;
}
```

The output is

```
 2 2 4
```

This means that logical OR works first. Does this mean that the operator precedence rule is violated here?

Comment: you `cout` 3 variables but your output shows 4 numbers. Do you mean `2 2 4`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Precedence just means that the expression is written as below

```
  ( (a++ || (b++ & c++)))
```

Once you do that, short circuiting means that just the first expression is evaluated.

This is why `a = 2` but `b` and `c` are unchanged.

[codepad](http://codepad.org/vbf9PmpY)

Comment: I was confusing precedence with associativity, I guess. Got it now.

Comment: @user1414696 Or commutativity ... see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property

Answer (score 1):

this link can help you :

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

**precedence**

**10**  &  Bitwise AND
**11**  ^  Bitwise XOR (exclusive or)
**12**  |  Bitwise OR (inclusive or)
**13**  &&  Logical AND
**14**  ||  Logical OR

this means that **'&'** is evaluated before **'||'**.

Comment: & has higher precedence. In this case, because the left side of the || is true, the right side with the & isn't evaluated at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's perfectly fine to learn about the precedence of these operators, just out of curiosity. In *real* life, this code without parentheses to make the intent absolutely clear is just unacceptable.

If the left side of an || has a non-zero value, then the right side isn't evaluated at all. It's guaranteed to be not evaluated.